# How to specify the multicolumn width in table header?

Tags: tables, width, multicolumn

I want to read/input the body of a table from a separate file. I have mostly solved this problem using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212089/how-to-read-body-of-table-from-a-separate-file).

But when I try to read a table with multicolumn from a separate file, it failed.
The following is an example.

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
%table.tex
    \hline
    A & B  & C & D  \\   \hline
    E & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{This is generated by excel2latex macro. I want to let it auto wrap according to the width of (B+C+D) }   \\      \hline

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Table test.

\section{Insert a full table}

    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    A & B  & C & D  \\   \hline
    E & \multicolumn{3}{p{6cm}|}{This is generated by excel2latex macro. I want to let it auto wrap according to the width of (B+C+D) }   \\      \hline
    \end{tabular}%

\section{ Input the body of table from a separate file}

\CatchFileDef{\mytable}{table.tex}{}% table.tex > \mytable
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  \mytable
    \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

I just don't want to manually define the width in the body of table because it is generated automatically.

Comment: I'm proposing that this posting be closed as the OP doesn't seem to be willing to express what you mean by the solution criteria "flexibility" and "elegance" and because neither of his/her own answers actually solve the problem set out in the posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that columns B, C, and D are of the `p` type with *usable* widths given by the length parameters `\colB`, `\colC`, and `\colD`. In your example code, these lengths are equal to `2cm` each. The *total* widths of columns B, C, and D are, however, *not* equal to `2cm`. Instead, each column's total width equals `2cm+2\tabcolsep`, where `\tabcolsep` is the parameter that governs the amount of whitespace inserted to the left and right of a column. (In the standard LaTeX document classes, the default value of this parameter is `6pt`.)

The *combined* width of columns B, C, and D -- not counting the widths of the vertical bars to the left of B and to the right of D -- is

```
\colB + \colC + \colD + 6\tabcolsep + 2\arrayrulewidth
```

(I'm assuming, implicitly, that the `array` package is being loaded. If that's not the case, then one should omit the `2\arrayrulewidth` term.) You can probably guess that `2\arrayrulewidth` represents the combined widths of the two interior vertical bars -- those separating B from C and C from D. The default value of this parameter is `0.4pt` in the standard document classes.

The *usable* width of the three columns is a bit smaller, since we mustn't impose on `\tabcolsep` at the left-hand edge of B and at the right-hand edge of D. It is thus given by

```
\colB + \colC + \colD + 4\tabcolsep + 2\arrayrulewidth
```

One can create a length variable called, say, `\combinedlength` and set its value to the expression above. The contents of the external file `table.tex` would thus be given by

```
\hline
A & B  & C & D  \\   \hline
E & \multicolumn{3}{p{\combinedlength}|}{This is generated by excel2latex macro. I want to let it auto wrap according to the width of (B+C+D) }   \\      
\hline
```

The full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,filecontents,catchfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
\hline
A & B  & C & D  \\   \hline
E & \multicolumn{3}{p{\combinedlength}|}{This is generated by excel2latex macro. I 
want to let it auto wrap according to the width of (B+C+D) }   \\      
\hline
\end{filecontents*}

%% Define some length parameters and set their values
\newlength\colB \setlength\colB{2cm}
\newlength\colC \setlength\colC{2cm}
\newlength\colD \setlength\colD{2cm}
\newlength\combinedlength 
\setlength\combinedlength{%
    \dimexpr\colB+\colC+\colD+4\tabcolsep+%
    2\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\begin{document}
\section{ Input the body of table from a separate file}

\CatchFileDef{\mytable}{table.tex}{}% table.tex > \mytable
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{\colB}|p{\colC}|p{\colD}|}
    \mytable
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. But I don't want to input the width directly such as  `` \dimexpr6cm+4'' . In fact, I read the table body from another seperate file, which is generated by Excel2latex macro. In the table body file, it only knows which columns are combined, but doesnot know the real width of each coloumn. I should find a method to compute the width after combination. For example, a special macro command in latex.

Comment: @JilongYin - Is *any* information available a priori about the widths of columns B, C, and D?

Comment: I can specify the width of B,C and D in a given table head. But the file including table body does not know it. I have tried using named variables. For example , I can generate code of the table body including \multicolumn{ncols}{p{\mywidth}}. Then I can \def\mywidth{5inch} every time before inputting table body file. But when the table includes two or more cells combined by multiple columns. This method fails. So I believe thre are some more direct and simple method than this though I am still searching.

Comment: @JilongYin - The file in which the table occurs doesn't need to "know" the widths, but the widths do have to be set *somewhere*, either as hardcoded values or as macros, e.g., `\widthB`, `\widthC`, and `\widthD`. If it's the latter, you could set the combined column's width as `p{\dimexpr \widthB+\widthC+\widthD +4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}`. All that's required is that `\widthB`, `\widthC`, and `\widthD` be defined in proper way by the time that the file which contains the combined column is processed by LaTeX.

Comment: @JilongYin - I've updated the answer to incorporate your comments. As you'll see, the external file just contains the expression `p{\combinedlength}`, where `\combinedlength` is a length variable that's defined and evaluated in the main tex file.

Comment: Yes, for this simple case, the problem can be solved by this ``forced'' method. But if the table becomes complex and large, it seems it is not a flexible and elegant method.

Comment: @JilongYin - I guess you need to state clearly how you understand the terms "flexible" and "elegant". Should I delete this answer since it doesn't meet your needs?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this by specifying \multicolumn{ncols}{ p{\tablewidth} }{long sentence...}

And then use a minipage enviroment outside of it

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
%table.tex
    \hline
    A & B  & C & D  \\   \hline
    E & \multicolumn{3}{ p{\tablewidth} }{This is generated by excel2latex macro. This is generated by excel2latex macro. This is generated by excel2latex macro. I want to let it auto wrap according to the width of (B+C+D) }   \\      \hline

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Table test.

\section{Insert a full table}

    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    A & B  & C & D  \\   \hline
    E & \multicolumn{3}{p{6cm}|}{This is generated by excel2latex macro. I want to let it auto wrap according to the width of (B+C+D) }   \\      \hline
    \end{tabular}%

\section{ Input the body of table from a separate file}

\CatchFileDef{\mytable}{table.tex}{}% table.tex > \mytable
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  \mytable
    \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is the macro `\tablewidth` defined? And where is the code for the `minipage` you mention at the top of your answer?

Comment: sorry, It should be \textwidth.

Comment: I　use p{\linewidth} replacing \textwidth, and it seems OK. Though the length is not same with B+C+D yet.

Comment: Using `\textwidth` as the argument of `p` will give you a table that's far wider (by about 2cm, i.e., the width of column A) than `\textwidth`...

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is too wide, especially in the case of several combined columns in a row. I wonder if there is another envrioment than tabular to solve this.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

I uses tabularx enviroment and its X coloumn format and solved this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{70mm}{|p{20mm}|p{20mm}|l|}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\hline
A     & B     & C \bigstrut\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|X|}{This is combined from A+B+C, and the contents is very very long.} \bigstrut\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: The table in this answer contains only three columns, whereas the one in your query had four. Whatever problem the table in this answer solves, it's not the one you posed earlier.

Comment: Yes, it is not a perfect solution yet. Anyway it has been solved temporarily. Thans for your long discussion.